# How do I import gems that have been downloaded when installing some software?

Tags: ruby

I am using Kali Linux, it has pre-installed a lot of software written in ruby (such as metasploit, beef), today I want to import a ssh gem when writing my own script, but I failed because it is fundamental It was not installed, but I saw that the software written in ruby also imported it. and it run well, How do they work?

Found in my system：

```
root@kali:/home# find / -type f -iname *ssh*.rb 
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/post/linux/manage/sshkey_persistence.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/post/multi/gather/ssh_creds.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/dos/windows/ssh/sysax_sshd_kexchange.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/ssh/ssh_login_pubkey.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/ssh/ssh_identify_pubkeys.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/ssh/ssh_enumusers.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/ssh/ssh_version.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/ssh/ssh_login.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/fuzzers/ssh/ssh_version_2.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/fuzzers/ssh/ssh_version_15.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/fuzzers/ssh/ssh_version_corrupt.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/fuzzers/ssh/ssh_kexinit_corrupt.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/linux/ssh/symantec_smg_ssh.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/linux/ssh/mercurial_ssh_exec.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/windows/ssh/freesshd_key_exchange.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/windows/ssh/freesshd_authbypass.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/windows/ssh/sysax_ssh_username.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/windows/ssh/securecrt_ssh1.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/apple_ios/ssh/cydia_default_ssh.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/multi/ssh/sshexec.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/dnsruby-1.60.2/test/tc_sshfp.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/dnsruby-1.60.2/lib/dnsruby/resource/SSHFP.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rex-socket-0.1.10/lib/rex/socket/ssh_factory.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/support/ssh_tunnel_bug.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/metasploit-credential-2.0.12/spec/models/metasploit/credential/ssh_key_spec.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/metasploit-credential-2.0.12/spec/factories/metasploit/credential/ssh_keys.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/metasploit-credential-2.0.12/app/models/metasploit/credential/ssh_key.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/metasploit-credential-2.0.12/db/migrate/20161107203710_create_index_on_private_data_and_type_for_ssh_key.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkey-1.9.0/test/sshkey_test.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkey-1.9.0/lib/sshkey.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/ssh.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/login_scanner/ssh.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/scripts/meterpreter/win32-sshclient.rb
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/scripts/meterpreter/win32-sshserver.rb
```

I also saw that they have a module that imports Net:SSH：

```
root@kali:/home# cat /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/ssh/ssh_login.rb
##
# This module requires Metasploit: https://metasploit.com/download
# Current source: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework
##

require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/command_stream'
require 'metasploit/framework/login_scanner/ssh'
require 'metasploit/framework/credential_collection'

...
...
...
```

but when i use it:

```
root@kali:/home# irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'net/ssh'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Can I use it in my script without using gem install?

Anyway, thank those who gave me advice, I hope you have a happy day~

Comment: You can install with [Bundler](https://bundler.io): `bundle install --path=.bundle` and then ship that whole thing if you want.

Comment: Where metasploit gets it from "/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb".  Where you are trying to get it from " /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/gems/2.3.0" metasploit is maintaining its own bundle (probably to ensure version control) if you would like to use this library in irb under the standard installation you should install the gem

Comment: The main problem is that for some reason I want to use local gems without using the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set `GEM_PATH` environment variable (with `ruby` or `irb`):

```
GEM_PATH=/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/ ruby -e 'require "net/ssh"'
```

Or you can set it in the code of your script:

```
#!/usr/env/ruby

Gem.paths = { 'GEM_HOME' => "/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/" }

require 'net/ssh'
```

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. `$LOAD_PATH` actually doesn't work with gems. You'd need to use `GEM_HOME`/`GEM_PATH` instead -- please see the updated answer.

Comment: it works !!!!!!!  I am so grateful to you.!!! you don know how I really want to give you a big hug now 

Comment: Haha, no problem. :-)